# CSS: Positioning of text

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at CSS's programming and have a question about text positioning. I have to design download button in CSS **without symbol font or images** in it. I've done that, but text doesn't want to fit inside box (picture 1).

[image: Text doen't fit inside the box]

This is my CSS code:

```
#download{
  background-color: rgb(0, 230, 0);
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 65px;
}

#download p{
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
  font-size: 30px;
  color:white;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}

#ikonad{
  border-radius: 150px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 179, 0);
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  height: 58px;
  width: 58px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.kvadrat{
  width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgb(0, 179, 0);
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
#trikotnik {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 12.5px;
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid rgb(0, 179, 0);
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Gumbi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="download">
<div id="ikonad">
<div class="kvadrat"><p>Download</p></div>
<div id="trikotnik"></div></div>

</div>
```

I would be glad, if anyone told me, what I did wrong. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the margin from your `<p>` element:

```
#download p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

(Side question: what is `padding-bottom: 300px` doing in there? Is that really necessary?)

Here's your markup with the added CSS rule:

```css
#download {
  background-color: rgb(0, 230, 0);
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 65px;
}
#download p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
#ikonad {
  border-radius: 150px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 179, 0);
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  height: 58px;
  width: 58px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.kvadrat {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 179, 0);
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
#trikotnik {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 12.5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid rgb(0, 179, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id="download">
  <div id="ikonad">
    <div class="kvadrat">
      <p>Download</p>
    </div>
    <div id="trikotnik"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!! I can't believe!! :D ... I tried a lot of things with that code, so I've decided to try with padding-bottom too. Thank you, bro; you saved my life!